# Значение поля VideoModePtr в структуре VbeInfoBlock

Tags: ассемблер, bios, osdev

Стандарт VESA(http://www.phatcode.net/res/221/files/vbe20.pdf) в структуре VbeInfoBlock определяет поле `VideoModePtr`:

```
struc VesaInfoBlock                 ;   VesaInfoBlock_size = 512 bytes
    .Signature              resb 4  ;   must be 'VESA'
    .Version                resw 1
    .OEMNamePtr             resd 1
    .Capabilities           resd 1

    .VideoModePtr           resd 1  ; <---- ?
 
    .CountOf64KBlocks       resw 1
    .OEMSoftwareRevision    resw 1
    .OEMVendorNamePtr       resd 1
    .OEMProductNamePtr      resd 1
    .OEMProductRevisionPtr  resd 1
    .Reserved               resb 222
    .OEMData                resb 256
endstruc
```

Это поле - 32-битный физический адрес или сегмент:смещение?
И может ли оказаться так, что структура ModeInfoBlock окажется выше 1МБ (если, например, я вызову `int 0x10`, `ax 0x4f00` с `es:di 0xffff:0xffff`)?